# Proving Tietze theorem on $\mathbb{R}$ line.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

This is sum no $5$ of chapter $4$ of Rudin.Since I am trying to do Rudin by myself I need someone to help me see whether I am on the right path.

Let $E$ be the closed set on $\mathbb{R}$ and there exists a continuous function $f(x)$ on $E$.Since there exists a continuous function on $E$. I believe that $E$ must be a union and the intersection of closed interval in such a way such that $E$ is itself a closed interval(my intuition behind this is that a function cannot be continuous if not defined on a interval)

If so then $E=[a,b]$ and we define $g(x)=f(x)$ when $x \in E$ and $g(x)=f(a)$ when $x < a$ and $g(x)=f(b)$ when $x > b$.I can then show that $g$ is a continuous function. Where am I getting it wrong?
I think I am getting it wrong in my intuition,  if so can someone help me to find a contradictory example.

Comment: A [continuous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Continuous_maps) can be defined on $E$ because $E$ is a [metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Definition). We do this using the epsilon-delta definition, similar to how usually it's done.

Comment: Also, include the details of your question in the body of the question

Comment: Yes I would. So is there an example of a continuous function on the set{$ {\frac{1}{n}:n \in N}$}?

Comment: Any constant function will do. Or just take any continuous $f:(0, 1]\to \mathbb{R}$, and restrict the domain.